# Is it possible to store contents of oracle apex interative report in Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We have a business process where the business will use an interactive report in order to identify data that will be used for decisions.  We would like to save the data that decisions are based on.  ie the contents of the IR which may have filtered the data.  Data in the database changes over time.

Of course the user could download the data as CSV...and then load it into the database again - but clearly this is a round-about process sure to annoy users.  It would be great if we could have a button on the IR page that when clicked would save the data currently shown on the IR.  Does anyone know if its possibly to cleaning do this?
Does oracle apex come with a way to identify the rows shown in all pages of a IR?

We are using Apex 18 (but likely to upgrade to 21 in near future)

Comment: You may be interested in this concept http://deneskubicek.blogspot.com/2013/05/getting-interactive-report-query.html

Comment: That looks very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, interactive **report** should be used to **view** data.

If you want to let users **modify** it, use an **interactive grid** instead.

Comment: We are not modifying data.  I think you may have misunderstood the question